# Finding concurrent occurences of values above/below a threshold in a Pandas DataFrame/Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to repeatedly scan columns in a Pandas DataFrame (I will refer to this as a Series) to determine the number of times a threshold is breached. What is making this more complicated is the following:

- The series is only considered to have breached the threshold if it is beyond the threshold for five consecutive points or more in the series.
- The series is only considered to have returned to normative levels if for five consecutive points or more after breaching the limit the series is back within the limit.

I'm trying to count the number of times the threshold is breached and the total number of points that the threshold is considered beyond the threshold.

For example, lets say the limit is if x >= 3 and with the following Series (I've formatted this as a list so it is easier to read, however in reality x would be a column in a DataFrame with N measurements):

x = [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, **5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **5, 5, 5, 5, 5**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

The desired result is that the threshold is breached twice, and the total number of points above the threshold is 13 (points in bold are considered in breach of the limit).

I can do this by looping through every point in the series however this is very slow. Through another question I found that the following can be used to find the number of times the series goes beyond a specified limit for more than five points:

```
df['breach'] = df['x'] >= limit   #Create a boolean column for when the series breaches the limit
df_limit = pd.DataFrame(df['breach'].values, columns=['breach_limit'])   #create a new dataframe using the boolean column
df_limit['count'] = df_limit['breach_limit'].groupby(df_limit['breach_limit'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).sum().replace(0, np.nan).dropna().reset_index(drop=True) #Count based aggregate of the column which results in the counts of every set of consecutive breaches in the series.
```

This would result in a count based aggregation of the total consecutive breaches. For example in the example above it would result in [4, 6, 1, 5]. You can then just discard the times that count is below five resulting in two breaches. However, this doesn't take into account allowing five points after the breach to return to normative levels or allow me to calculate the total points.

Has anyone got any suggestions for how to do this in a way which wouldn't use for loops so I can speed up the analysis which is prohibitively slow when using for loops.

Comment: I think the fastest you are able to do this is in `O(N)` time. You would have to loop once over array `x` to determine if an element of that array is above a treshhold or not,

Comment: Yes I think you are probably correct? Do you know if there will be any speed increase by attempting to use the built in Pandas methods such as the aggregation methods over just looping through the data set once using a for loop?